# Magent2 css, js not loading both admin and front end

Tags: javascript, css, magento2

I have installed  Magent2.2 on centOs. Installation part successfully completed. When I visited the front and I found no assets like CSS/JS and images not loaded. I have google last two day and tried a dirrefrent solution like Magento permission issue, deploy static content etc, but no luck anymore.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check if you have .htaccess on the pub/static/ if no - upload it from the install package. Also check if you really have those files that are not loading.

Comment: Thanks for reply my questions @macas. I have resolved that issue.